# How to readline() without blocking

Tags: stream, readline, nonblocking

Im trying to readline from console input using the System.readline() stream.
I want the method to check whether a line was inserted to console, and if so check if its equale to "Exit". if a line was not inserted to the console I want the method to do nothing.

```
    /**
 * this method checks if the Exit command with written on the Servers console
 */
private void checkIfTypedExitOnKeyboard() {



    System.out.println("checking if user printed Exit:-)");//DELETE TEST
   long end=System.currentTimeMillis()+2000;
    InputStreamReader fileInputStream=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileInputStream);
    try
    {   
       while(System.currentTimeMillis()<end && bufferedReader.ready() && (bufferedReader.readLine()!=null))
            {   
                if (bufferedReader.ready() && fileInputStream.ready() && bufferedReader.readLine().equals("Exit")){//TODO fix this
                    System.out.println("Reactor is shutting down");
                    stopReactor();
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(java.io.IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

why doesnt this code work??

thanks:-)

Comment: P.S tried to find info about this in few other posts but nothing seems to do the job.. if you know how to do this youll be of great help to me:-)

Comment: need your help.. please:-)